# Можно ли с помощью PDB подключится к активному интерпретатору

Tags: python, отладка

Нужно подключиться к активному интерпретатору, чтобы отладить один мерзкий кусок кода. Проблема в том, что если поставить в коде `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` или просто вывод на консоль какой-то информации для отладки, код начинает работать **нормально**. Соответственно, нужен какой-то способ начать отлаживать уже запущенный Python-процесс.

Comment: У вас однопоточный код?

Comment: @AndrioSkur нет

Comment: Ну нормального дебаггера для многопоточного исполнения нет. Но судя потому что вы говорите у вас просто не синхронизирован доступ к данным между потоками. Нужно больше инфы по коду)

Comment: Там гонки данных никакой быть не должно быть, так как логика такая: поток создает другой поток и ждет его выполнения какое-то время, после чего, если дочерний не успел, убивает весь скрипт. Но дело в том, что в какой-то момент "дочерний" поток просто виснет. Причем стоит добавить `print("1")`, например, и все работает (в "дочернем" в цикле выполняются действия). Сейчас висит костыль с `sys.stdout.write("\0"); sys.stdout.flush()`, но это плохо. Просто свой код скинуть не смогу, NDA и все такое, и воспроизвести эту ошибку я не могу, к сожалению, видимо ситуация ОЧЕНЬ специфичная (или я дурак).

Comment: @AndrioSkur но вообще именно интересует, можно ли запустить pdb (или что-то другое) и из него сделать attach к другому процессу и отлаживать обычный питон.

Comment: Сдесь поглядите. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162674/enter-pdb-with-kill-signal Хотя я не уверен что это поможет